# Самопересекающаяся поверхность OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl

с помощью openGL строю поверхность которая сама себя пересекает, как можно визуально избавиться от наложения, так что бы грани не были видны. Пробовал через тест глубины и PolygonOffset не помогает 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы же ставили polygonOffset только для половины ленты?

Comment: Лента у меня цельная и идет одной поверхностью + их будет очень много и я ищу универсальный вариант